# How to remove Landsat 7 SLC gapmask in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am using the Collection 1 Tier 1 Surface reflectance image collection.  I have applied the GEE provided cloudmasking to this collection as well as other Landsat collections.  On export, striping is negatively affecting my work and I would rather have GEE just treat the SLC missing pixels as null/NaN.

I would like to have my Landsat 7 imagery be like the left column:
[image]

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3e76b080d9fa47acd1e3ee9fb69e36bc)

```js
//Date created 05/07/2020


// Required Packages
// ===================
// * Google Earth Engine API


// Required Data Inputs 
// ===================
// * USGS/NASA's Landsat 4 surface reflectance tier 1 dataset (August 1982 - December 1993)
// * USGS/NASA's Landsat 5 surface reflectance tier 1 dataset (January 1, 1984 - May 5, 2012)
// * USGS/NASA's Landsat 7 surface reflectance tier 1 dataset (January 1, 1999 - December 31, 20198)
// * USGS/NASA's Landsat 8 surface reflectance tier 1 dataset (April 11, 2013 - December 31, 2019)
// * Study Area Polygon

var cloudCoveragePercentage = 15;
var startYear = '1982';
var startDate = '-05-01';
var endYear = '2019';
var endDate = '-08-31';
// var datePlaceFilterStart = '1982-05-01';
// var datePlaceFilterEnd = '2019-08-31';
var subsetUnused = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-143.8312008736224, 66.35690350134108],
          [-143.8312008736224, 65.6600907815845],
          [-141.5240719673724, 65.6600907815845],
          [-141.5240719673724, 66.35690350134108]]], null, false);
var studyRegion = subsetUnused; 
var timePeriod = "May-Aug";

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//                        Loading Landsat 4, 5, 7 with cloudmask
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

    // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
    // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  
    // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

    // Apply Cloudmask to L4.5.7
var L4 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_SR")
                  .map(cloudMaskL457);

var L5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
                  .map(cloudMaskL457);

var L7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
                  .map(cloudMaskL457);



//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//                  Loading Landsat 8 with cloudmask
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
function maskL8sr(image) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  
    // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');

    // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

    //Define collection
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .map(maskL8sr);
                  
                  
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Merge Landsat 4, 5, 8 imagery collections and filter all by date/place
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

//Merge Landsat 4, 5 , 7 '

var L457 = L4.merge(L5).merge(L7);

var L457DatePlace= L457.filterBounds(studyRegion);
var L8DatePlace= L8.filterBounds(studyRegion);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//                 Select the bands that you will need  
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Green, Red, NIR, MIR 
var L457_B3_B4 = L457DatePlace.select(['B3','B4']);    
var L8_B4_B5 = L8DatePlace.select(['B4','B5']);


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//                 Rename the bands for consistency  
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

var L457Renamed = L457_B3_B4.select(
    ['B3', 'B4'], // old names
    ['red', 'NIR']); // new names
print ('L457Renamed', L457Renamed);

var L8Renamed = L8_B4_B5.select(
    ['B4', 'B5'], // old names
    ['red', 'NIR']); // new names
print ('L8Renamed', L8Renamed);


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//                 Merge all satellite collections  
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

var mergedCollection = L457Renamed.merge(L8Renamed);
print ('mergedCollection', mergedCollection);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//                  Filter imagery to given cloud cover percentage
//--------------------------------------------------------------------


var filtered = mergedCollection
  .filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVER', cloudCoveragePercentage));
print('Cloud Coverage', cloudCoveragePercentage + "%");
print('unfiltered size', mergedCollection.size());
print('filtered size', filtered.size());  

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//                     Create NDVI Collection 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['NIR', 'red']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var withNDVI = filtered.map(addNDVI);
print ('withNDVI', withNDVI);

var mergedNDVI = withNDVI.select(['NDVI']);
print ('mergedNDVI', mergedNDVI);


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//                     Take the mean for each year   
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

    // This will result in a single raster for each collection
var image = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(ee.List.sequence(Number(startYear), Number(endYear)).map(function(year){
  var yearlyMean = mergedNDVI.filterDate(ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1,1), 
                                        ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year).add(1),1,1))
                                        .mean();
  return yearlyMean.rename(ee.String('NDVI').cat(ee.Number(year).format('%04d')))
}))
// to single image
  .toBands()
// clip to a featurecollection
  .clip(studyRegion)
print(image)

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//       Export as GeoTIFF
//--------------------------------------------------------------------


  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: 'subset'/*+ "_" + startYear*/ + '_NDVI-mean' + '_CC_' + cloudCoveragePercentage + 'percent',
    scale: 30,
    region: studyRegion,
    maxPixels: 10000000000000,
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
    formatOptions: {
      cloudOptimized: true
    },
    skipEmptyTiles: true
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The L7 SCL-off gaps *are* being set as null/NaN. When you apply the `cloudMaskL457` function, it masks out the gaps as well as clouds and cloud shadows. Later you calculate the annual mean, which generates a composite from multiple images, minor L7 gap artifacts often show up in composites. The alternative is to not mask them, which would produce an even worse composite, because the gaps are represented as value 0, which would drag the mean down.

A demonstration of gaps being masked out after application of the `cloudMaskL457` function:

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8febc106d425bd1d5fa226f712e187ff)

```js
// Add to the end of your script.  
var l7Img = L7.filterBounds(studyRegion).filterDate('2006-07-01', '2006-08-01').first();
Map.addLayer(l7Img, {bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B2'], min: 100, max: 3500}, 'L7 Image masked');
```

[image]